# MSGraph groups webhook eventTime

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm listening to groups endpoint via webhook.

I perform the follow actions via Outlook Online +Group

1. Create Group
2. Set Owner
3. Add one member

I got a webhook event for all three at once, this is fine, I assume things are batched.  But the eventTime is identical – which makes it difficult to understand the order these events happened.  So I was asking for clarification whether the resourceData.eventTime should be the same, or should they have been different.

```js
{
  "value": [
    {
      "changeType": "updated",
      "clientState": "its_me_flow",
      "resource": "Groups/7763cbdb-7f79-4b95-bb3b-d8e83413f7ad",
      "resourceData": {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.Group",
        "@odata.id": "Groups/7763cbdb-7f79-4b95-bb3b-d8e83413f7ad",
        "id": "7763cbdb-7f79-4b95-bb3b-d8e83413f7ad",
        "organizationId": "26e65220-5561-46ef-9783-ce5f20489241",
        "eventTime": "2018-02-13T00:20:03.9107966Z"
      },
      "subscriptionExpirationDateTime": "2018-02-13T04:07:19.7318815+00:00",
      "subscriptionId": "c8c521bf-2bcb-4b93-821f-40a1fb72c0f8"
    },
    {
      "changeType": "updated",
      "clientState": "its_me_flow",
      "resource": "Groups/7763cbdb-7f79-4b95-bb3b-d8e83413f7ad",
      "resourceData": {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.Group",
        "@odata.id": "Groups/7763cbdb-7f79-4b95-bb3b-d8e83413f7ad",
        "id": "7763cbdb-7f79-4b95-bb3b-d8e83413f7ad",
        "organizationId": "26e65220-5561-46ef-9783-ce5f20489241",
        "eventTime": "2018-02-13T00:20:03.9107966Z",
        "owner@delta": [
          {
            "id": "36e3b856-3c2e-4605-ac5f-99064d229c3a"
          }
        ]
      },
      "subscriptionExpirationDateTime": "2018-02-13T04:07:19.7318815+00:00",
      "subscriptionId": "c8c521bf-2bcb-4b93-821f-40a1fb72c0f8"
    },
    {
      "changeType": "updated",
      "clientState": "its_me_flow",
      "resource": "Groups/7763cbdb-7f79-4b95-bb3b-d8e83413f7ad",
      "resourceData": {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.Group",
        "@odata.id": "Groups/7763cbdb-7f79-4b95-bb3b-d8e83413f7ad",
        "id": "7763cbdb-7f79-4b95-bb3b-d8e83413f7ad",
        "organizationId": "26e65220-5561-46ef-9783-ce5f20489241",
        "eventTime": "2018-02-13T00:20:03.9107966Z",
        "members@delta": [
          {
            "id": "36e3b856-3c2e-4605-ac5f-99064d229c3a"
          },
          {
            "id": "9b47aca9-efc6-488c-8afd-c323eccad4b4"
          }
        ]
      },
      "subscriptionExpirationDateTime": "2018-02-13T04:07:19.7318815+00:00",
      "subscriptionId": "c8c521bf-2bcb-4b93-821f-40a1fb72c0f8"
    }
  ]
}
```

see the eventTime is identical.  From the looks of the owner@delta and members@delta it looks like the order is correct, but is can I trust the array order?  Much prefer if the eventTime was sequential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to receiving a page of changes via Delta Query, where many objects can be included a single page and order of changed object in a page follows some logic order. (eg: in your case owner add followed by member add).

Since ordering of events is not guaranteed with webhooks, eventTime is meant to help order pages of events received at different points of time. ex: Microsoft graph is attempting to send pages of changes P1 and P2 at time T1 and T2. However the target webhook endpoint was down at time T1, so Microsoft graph will retry with exponential delay upto 4 hours. While webhook endpoint might be available at time T2. So page P2 is received first, followed by P1 in this case. To help clients distinguish and order events on their end, eventTime field can be used.

Comment: So the clarification is that eventTime will always be in batches of T1 or T2 so in my case where the three changes have identical eventTime is by design?  

Perhaps this clarification should be added to the documentation.

Additional question - can the order of the changes be trusted: so change[0] is before change[1] before change[2] in my case.

Comment: Correct. And , thanks for the feedback on the documentation, We will update those. Yes, you should be able to trust the order of changes within a batch which have same time stamp.